# Issue with Rocky Linux System not showing deactivated ports

Tags: linux-networking, port, rocky-linux

I am having issues with a Rocky Linux system that a colleague is using. They are currently connected via 1gig ports and they want to use the 10gig ports on the switch. However, when looking for the deactivated ports they do not show up at all. nmcli connection show only shows the two 1gig ports. We have tried everything to get this to work we would use nmcli con up if we could figure out what the port is called. I am not super familiar with Rocky linux commands so I am sure I am missing something. Could someone give me some ideas of where to go next?

Comment: Are the 10g NICs visible in the output of `lspci`?

Comment: They are not which is strange. I am not sure of the original set up of these switches either and of course the departing employees who handled it did not leave any sort of spark notes on the set up or anything.

Comment: Now I'm confused; do the machines actually have 10gig NICS? The switch ports are relevant to that question. If the NICs exist, and they don't show up in the `lspci` output, it's possible they're disabled in the BIOS, maybe? That's the first place I would check.

Comment: I am leaning towards it being a driver related issue. But I’ll also check bios and yeah I confirmed they actually existed. That was my first concern. Thanks I’ll follow up when I’m back in the office.